# Doctrine 2: UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = 1

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to accomplish this (mysql) query:

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + 1 WHERE id = 1
```

What is the correct way of doing the above using a Doctrine 2 entity?

***Edit**

I'm looking for a way to do `$entity->incrementField()`, which execute the above mysql query on `flush()`

Comment: `UPDATE table t SET t.field = t.field+1 WHERE t.id = 1`?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find a way to do this using the entity itself. I have solved this now by utilizing a regular DQL which does increment, and update model/entity with result.

Answer (score -2):

It won't lead to the exact same query, but maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
class MyEntity {
    private $field;

    public function incrementField() {
        $this->field++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It will then try to save the exact value of $field, not increment it (and then any increments done from another frontend in the meantime will get lost)